# Google Data Studio Date Range Filter -Report Level

Tags: looker-studio

I am creating multiple reports in Google DataStudio, I want to persist my date range selection for all reports.
I have made date range control as 'Report Level'
If I am creating multiple pages on same reports then It is working fine but it is not working for different reports ?

Is it possible to achieve this functionality for different reports ?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Reports (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

You can't make connections like this between different reports. Data Studio treats them completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can Arrange -> Group a control with various visualization charts, to allow one control to affect multiple charts. Here's Google's documentation on how to apply a single control to multiple charts:

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7514442?hl=en&ref_topic=6371413

If your charts are using different data sources, or blended data sources, then you can follow Google's guidelines for using controls across different data sources:

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9173975?hl=en&ref_topic=6371413